# Fiscal verification of invoices Slovenia

Tags: java, soap, fiscal

I am trying to consume an Invoice SOAP Web Service in Slovenia. However I have some problem with it. In order to consume an Invoice Web Service, I need to send BusinessPremises SOAP Web Service, but I get an error while using this service.

Request :

```
<BusinessPremise>
    <TaxNumber>123456</TaxNumber>
    <BusinessPremiseID>testtt</BusinessPremiseID>
    <BPIdentifier>
        <RealEstateBP>
            <PropertyID>
                <CadastralNumber>365</CadastralNumber>
                <BuildingNumber>12</BuildingNumber>
                <BuildingSectionNumber>3</BuildingSectionNumber>
            </PropertyID>
            <Address>
                <Street>Dunajska cesta</Street>
                <HouseNumber>24</HouseNumber>
                <HouseNumberAdditional>B</HouseNumberAdditional>
                <Community>Ljubljana</Community>
                <City>Ljubljana</City>
                <PostalCode>1000</PostalCode>
            </Address>
        </RealEstateBP>
    </BPIdentifier>
    <ValidityDate>2020-05-02</ValidityDate>
    <SoftwareSupplier>
        <TaxNumber>10436359</TaxNumber>
    </SoftwareSupplier>
    <SpecialNotes>Primer prijave poslovnega prostora</SpecialNotes>
</BusinessPremise>
```

Response :

```
<fu:Error>
  <fu:ErrorCode>S003</fu:ErrorCode>
  <fu:ErrorMessage>Digitalni podpis ni ustrezen</fu:ErrorMessage>
</fu:Error>
```

Comment: What about giving some more context? Many of us here don't speak slovenian...

Comment: do you have permission to use that web service? Maybe you need some specific user/pwd or credentials

Comment: "Digital signature its not valid" check the web service contract, the right format of each value, probably you are missing some headers credentials